# Rounded corners on table cells

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is 'no' but I'll ask it nevertheless.

I'm designing a form in InDesign (the kind of thing you might get from a bank, a big light grey box, with white spaces to indicate areas that need to be filled out). I want to make the white spaces have slightly rounded corners, but ideally I'd like to build this as a table.

**Is there a (hacky) way to give the cells of an InDesign table rounded corners?**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, sort of. You can place a textbox inside the table and round that. The technique is a bit tedious but I'm sure somebody has written a script to manage this, if not one could be made.

[image]

**Image 1**: Table with textboxes that have rounded corners

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It would be great if there was a way to have the text boxes resize automatically when you adjust the columns and rows.

Comment: @Alex that is why i said it should be scripted.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a method that was easy...

1) draw rounded squares on top of your cells you want rounded.

2) copy all the rounded squares to Illustrator, and use Object/Compound Path/Make to turn the collection of rounded squares into one compound shape.

3) copy them back to indesign, aim it over the table.

4) cut your table, select the psted set of squares, and use Edit/Paste Into. Everything is now rounded and the original text is still easily editable.

5) to make it look its best, make the set of rounded squares set to None for color